# Cloudformation 'Recreate' an RDS instance. Does it restore the data?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS Postgres Instance and I would like to change a setting that requires the database be recreated as part of the Cloudformation Update Stack. Specifically, the initial database was created with a DBSnapshotIdentifier that I want to remove but removing this line from the Cloudformation definition requires a recreate of the instance.

If I do this, will the new database have all of the data that was in the replaced database instance or will it be a blank RDS instance? I assume it will restore the data but I just want to be certain.

The docs are not 100% clear and obviously I need to be certain of what's going to happen.

Can anybody confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I do this, will the new database have all of the data that was in the replaced database instance or will it be a blank RDS instance?

No, it won't. The new RDS instance will be empty after the stack update is done.

I agree that this isn't perfectly clear from the AWS documentation, but [Update Behaviors of Stack Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html)  does state it between the lines, as it suggests to create a snapshot before the stack update to be able to restore the data afterwards.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted but thank you for confirming.